# Difference between ag-grid packages

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

There are multiple ag-grid packages available in npm. I haven't found any decent documentation which explains differences between them. What are minimum ag-grid packages required for enterprise grid in angular app?

1. differences between ag-grid-enterprise and @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules
2. differences between ag-grid-community and @ag-grid-community/all-modules. When using ag-grid-enterprise v22 is it explicitly required to install ag-grid-community or @ag-grid-community/all-modules.

Comment: See the following article for updated details https://blog.ag-grid.com/minimising-bundle-size/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages (modules) are explained in [this part of the ag-Grid docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-modules/)

If you are confused, them best is just ignore all the packages and follow the [getting started guides](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-getting-started/).

In a nutshell, you can ignore most of the packages and just include everything like the Getting Started guides do. Then come back and look at how to load individual packages if you want to reduce your bundle size and are not using all the features.

Answer (score 2):

1. [ag-grid-community](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-community) is the base javascript package [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) provides.
2. [ag-grid-enterprise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-enterprise) - use this only, if you would like to use enterprise features and have enterprise license.
3. [ag-grid-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-angular) - if you need to use [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) with angular framework, use this.

   > Similarly, [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) also provides framework friendly packages like [ag-grid-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-react), [ag-grid-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-vue).

For your `.../all-modules` related questions, not sure if those are valid or not, but if you want to use [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) with [[image]angular](/questions/tagged/angular), the above mentioned packages are there 
 for you.

[Add-ag-grid-to-your-project](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/#add-ag-grid-to-your-project) this link will help you get started with this.

Answer (score 1):

As of v27 the all-modules packages are no longer recommended instead you should just use the following packages to have access to all the grid features.

```json
"ag-grid-community": "^27.0.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^27.0.1"
```

You only need to worry about the scoped packages if you are trying to reduce your bundle size. In that case, you should include the specific feature modules that you require.

From the [docs](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/modules/#mixing-packages-and-modules)

> It is important that you do not mix packages and modules in the same
> application as this will result in AG Grid being included twice and
> doubling your bundle size! All modules are scoped by either
> @ag-grid-community/* or @ag-grid-enterprise/* and should not be mixed
> with the standalone packages of ag-grid-community and
> ag-grid-enterprise.

| Modules | Packages |
| --- | --- |
| @ag-grid-community/xxxxx | ag-grid-community |
| @ag-grid-enterprise/xxxxx | ag-grid-enterprise |

I have written about this more in this [blog post](https://blog.ag-grid.com/minimising-bundle-size/).